# How to call AccurateTax.com XML API service?

Tags: php, xml, soap, service

I am newbie and need help with accuratetax.com xml api service call.

What currently I am doing is:

```
$client = new nusoap_client($serviceURL, false);
$result = $client->call('method', $xmlContents);
```

I don't know what "method" need to be called in this case.
And let me know if I am doing wrong and where.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Did you read the API documentation?

Comment: Yes I did but there is not enough information in the api document. That's why I came here..

Answer (score 0):

The method element denotes the lookup method used to fulfill the sales tax request.   An 'A' is for address-level, Z for zip-code, and 4 for zip+4...it gives you the granularity of the sales tax response's lookup...some states zipcode is sufficient, others require address level.

You should not need to pass this however through when calling for the request to be processed, method is only set in the response method.

Best, 
Pete @ Accuratetax.com

Answer (score 0):

The AccurateTax.com webservice does not use SOAP.  So its just as simple as sending over the proper XML.

So you would use curl to post the XML over to the service URL.